# How to use mercurial from nant

Tags: mercurial, build, nant

I have a little private Google code project. For a SCM I use Mercurial. And for the local build i would like to use nant.

So basically:

1. I would like to download my source files from a known mercurial repository using a nant task
2. I would like to somehow get the revision number of the repository so that I can assemble a nice little assembly version number

The build script will not be used for continuous integration but only for nightly builds and production builds.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know nant, but in (real) ant, we just use the `<exec>` task to invoke the hg binary.  Depending clean you'd like to start you can `clone` or just `pull` and executing `hg id -i` gets you the revision number cleanly.  Another thing to consider is using the archive links on the remote web interface (essentially the hg archive command via HTTP) and just use wget (not the equivalent nant task) to pull down the tip archive, which has an easy consistent link, and then you can get the revision id from inside the archive's `hg_archival.txt` file.

Comment: That would work but at the same time imply that the end-user of the script would have to have mercurial installed locally.

I was honestly hoping that some taks extensions were available

Comment: I don't think you'll find any non-mercurial code that speaks the mercurial wire protocol currently, and it's in python.  So you could try running it in IronPython, but at that point you're talking as much work as a mercurial install.  I'll re-write my get based soln in a separate answer.

Answer (score 2):

Since you're looking for NANT code rather than calling off to the mercurial binary, I'd suggest just using Nant's `<get>` task to pull down the tip of your repo like this:

```
<get src="http://bitbucket.org/tortoisehg/stable/get/tip.zip" dest="latest.zip" />
<unzip zipfile="latest.zip" todir="latest"/>
```

and inside there should be a `.hg_archival.txt` file that contains something like this:

```
repo: bac32db38e52fd49acb62b94730a55f4f4b0cdee
node: 61482ea34fd0b9650e738eaebb2fe352c2f6315a
```

from which you can get a hashId suitable for use in branding a build.

Unfortunately, I'm not finding the archive download links on google code, but they're pretty standard in the mercurial (and bitbucket) web interfaces, so I'd imagine they're somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

While this wouldn't have been applicable to the person originally asking the question, I needed to do something similar... but I needed the numeric revision (yes, I know the number is repository-specific, but in the context where the script was getting used this was fine). I also had no problems with calling hg.exe, because everywhere this might be run from hg.exe is available.

The NAnt script I finally ended up with was this:

```
<exec program="hg.exe" output="CurrentMercurialRevision.txt">
    <arg value="id" />
    <arg value="-n" />
</exec>
<loadfile file="CurrentMercurialRevision.txt" property="buildNumber" />
```

Unfortunately, there doesn't appear to be a way in NUnit to read directly into a property, so I had to use the intermediate text file and process it into a property by using loadfile. I also had to add "CurrentMercurialRevision.txt" to the .hgignore file... but if you're familiar with Mercurial you had probably already guessed that. ;-)

Hopefully this will help someone.

Comment: I came across this thread when searching one of my questions. There is a cool msbuild community taks written specially for "Mercurial" [here](http://msbuildhg.codeplex.com/). Using this you don't have to use any intermediate file for this task.